Azure data factory Switch condition sometime is taking a lot longer time to complete
we have Azure data factory pipeline which on average takes 5-6 minute to complete. It's simple pipeline containing one switch activity and one data copy activity.
Sometimes, we have observed that switch activity takes more than 2hr to complete. Anyone knows why sometime switch activity is taking long time?
pipeline execution screenshot

This is just a guess, but I've witnessed similar behavior in the past. If you can view the Monitor status while the job is active, the Copy Data activity is probably in a queue or pending state for the majority of this time. When it finally activates and completes, it reports itself as just the couple minutes it took to run.

hi @JoelCochran - You are right, and we have seen this ADF behavior. But this issue is not only because of CopyData activity, we have seen sometime Switch activity takes lot of time 10+minute

This could occur with any activity inside the Switch (or If or Foreach as well) if the system ends up queueing the activity for some reason. If you know it should only take a few minutes, you could put a timeout and retry on the Switch.
